# How can I stop reading for values and execute the else statement

Tags: c, scanf, interrupt

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   


    int a, b, c, d, e, f, r=0; 
    r=scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
    if(r==6)
    {
        printf( "Hello" );
    } 
    else
    {
        printf( "BOOM!!\n" );
        printf("The bomb has blown up");
    }

}
```

I want the scanf to take only few inputs < 6 and jump to the else part and execute it.

Comment: You can, just type something that is not numbers and press enter.

Comment: Read a _line_ of user input into a _string_ with `fgets()`, then parse it for `int`.

Comment: Just enter `coderredoc` and it would fail. (Anything not a number you can put and press enter - it would fail.

Comment: Note that the trailing newline in the format string forces `scanf()` to keep reading until it gets a non-white-space character in the input after the 6th number.

Comment: Do you really have problems with getting the else part executed?  I feel that the idea of this is that it actually is meant to be the *easy* part. Can you describe what you do that gets the "then" part executed?